# What has been the difference between Kramnik and Anand?

Tags: psychology

Both players are above 40, but Kramnik is still rated #2 in the world and is rated close to 2800, whereas Anand's rating has steadily been falling. What has Kramnik done to get better with age, which Anand has not been able to do ?

Comment: At Kramnik's age Anand was still world champion … by the way, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster I don't particularly care for votes so it's ok. Thanks for your observation.

Answer (score 4):

Anand is 5 and a half years older than Kramnik. If you go back 5 and a half years, you'll see that [Anand peaked in 2011](http://2700chess.com) with a live rating of 2817.

So the idea that Kramnik somehow kept his rating high in way Anand has not been able to is completely wrong.

Comment: Good point. I thought they were closer in age, for some reason. So, would you say that Kramnik would be out of the top 15 in 5 years ?

Comment: Anand still is in the top ten right now, so I don't see why Kramnik shouldn't be. But of course sooner or later everybody declines.

Comment: The Wikipedia page says Anand is no 12 in the world. By the way, what are your thoughts on Pentala Harikrishnan ? Will he be top 5 someday ?

Comment: Harikrishna has gotten very strong in recent years, but there are quite a lot of younger players ahead of him, so I wouldn't bet on it. It's just unlikely that he will improve more than Carlsen, Caruana, Karjakin, So, Ding Liren, MVL, Giri, Rapport etc who are all at least 5 years younger.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm backing Wei Yi to become the next world champion. What are your thoughts ?

Comment: The rating notwithstanding, do you think Anand peaked as a chess player in 2011 ? I ask because most of his career was before I was interested in chess, (and some of it even before I was born).

Comment: I would put the peak of Anand's career at 2008 when he defeated Kramnik in Bonn very convincingly. But I might be biased because I saw most of the games on site.

Comment: Above when he beat Kasparov in 1994 ? (That was before I was born. Lol) I think we can agree that 2011 was not his peak. He was no longer the Lightning calculator, and was the underdog when he played Carlsen. Why do you think the ratings peaked at that time of his career ? Is the rating system not accurate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43069/discussion-between-blindkungfumaster-and-user230452).

Answer (score 0):

[The difference between Kramnik's and Anand's ratings is basically just noise.](http://2700chess.com/charts/kramnik,anand?date-from=2010-03-01&date-to=2016-08-01) They have been trading places on the rating list for over 20 years. Less than a year ago (September 2015), Anand's rating was higher than Kramnik's by the same amount that Kramnik's is currently higher than Anand's.

Comment: Whom do you consider the better player ?

Comment: I don't consider either to be better than the other.

Answer (score -2):

Anand seems to play a lot more than Kramnik, and five years age difference in the 40s is a considerable difference. I don't think Harikrishna will be top 5.